# Themes Font or Symbols not Working properly with Windows Terminal

Tags: windows, powershell, terminal

[image]

I am trying to install Oh my posh and Oh my git in Power shell through windows terminal but the fonts or the symbols are not correctly loading in, tried reinstalling the themes again and changing the ps1 profile doc, but the problem continues. Tried installing Nerd Fonts too, the fonts work in WSL Ubuntu, but not in Powershell in the Windows terminal.